# Comparing the freshly inputted text to a list of available commands in asm

Tags: assembly, nasm, qemu, 16-bit

how do i compare the string in the `buffer` with a command like `'--help'`
how would you compare the freshly inputted text in the buffer with a command here is my code

````
xor  ax, ax
mov  ds, ax
mov  es, ax
cld
;bg
MOV AH, 06h   
XOR AL, AL    
XOR CX, CX    
MOV DX, 184FH  
MOV BH, 1Eh  
INT 10H
;cursor
mov dh, 1
mov dl, 30
mov bh, 0
mov ah, 2
int 10h
;text
  mov  si, msg     
  mov  bh, 0      
  lodsb
More:
  mov  ah, 0Eh     ; BIOS.Teletype
  int  10h
  lodsb            
  cmp  al, 0
  jnz  More
;cursor
mov dh, 3
mov dl, 2
mov bh, 0
mov ah, 2
int 10h
;commandline

Key:
    mov  di, buf   
Next:
    mov  ah, 00h   ;GetKeyboardKey
    int  16h       
    stosb          
    mov  bh, 0     
    mov  ah, 0Eh   ; BIOS.Teletype
    int  10h
    cmp  al, 13
    jne  Next      
    mov  al, 10   
    int  10h


buf  db '........'
help db '--help'
msg  db 'WELCOME TO DARSHOS', 0
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55```
````

Comment: Intel has the command [CMPS](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmps:cmpsb:cmpsw:cmpsd:cmpsq) for comparing strings. However, I don't think that creating a toy-OS and writing boot sector is a good way to start with learning assembly. Search for examples of ordinary executable programs and write/debug your code in this format first.

Comment: I disagree, writing low-level PC assembly is a great way (I'd say second-best to starting on a microcontroller) to learn assembly. If that's what interests you, don't feel discouraged from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> help db '--help'
> ```

It's not clear why you have prefixed this command with those '--'.

For a practical approach to the task, consider next list of available commands:

```
list  db  'cls', 13
      db  'help', 13
      db  'date', 13
      db  13
```

Below is one method of searching through this list of CarriageReturn-terminated ASCII strings where no string has more than 7 text characters plus a terminating byte (13). That's 8 in total since that was the limit we chose on inputting the command that we're trying to locate.

The snippet uses a couple of string instructions:

- The `lodsb` string instruction loads the byte at `DS:SI` into the `AL` register. This will automatically advance the pointer. If the direction flag `DF` is clear it will increment by one.
- The `scasb` string instruction will compare the `AL` register with the byte at `ES:DI`. This will modify flags that we can interrogate and it will also automatically advance the pointer.

```
  cld
  mov  si, list
NextItemOnList:
  mov  di, buf          ; Contains the command we want to find (terminated by 13)
NextChar:
  lodsb
  scasb
  jne  NotThisOne
  cmp  al, 13
  jne  NextChar
Found:
  ...
NotThisOne:
  dec  si               ; Back to where the mismatch occured
SkipRemainder:
  lodsb                 ; Skip remainder of this list item
  cmp  al, 13
  jne  SkipRemainder
  cmp  byte [si], 13    ; EndOfList ?
  jne  NextItemOnList   ; No
NotFound:
  ...
```

With the above code we can find out if the command is on the list, but which was it?

- We can choose to associate an index with each command on the list, like in:

```
  cld
  xor  cx, cx           ; cls=0, help=1, date=2
  mov  si, list
NextItemOnList:
  mov  di, buf          ; Contains the command we want to find (terminated by 13)
NextChar:
  lodsb
  scasb
  jne  NotThisOne
  cmp  al, 13
  jne  NextChar
Found:
  ...
NotThisOne:
  dec  si               ; Back to where the mismatch occured
SkipRemainder:
  lodsb                 ; Skip remainder of this list item
  cmp  al, 13
  jne  SkipRemainder
  inc  cx               ; Next index
  cmp  byte [si], 13    ; EndOfList ?
  jne  NextItemOnList   ; No
NotFound:
  ...
```

- Or we can add to the list the actual addresses where the commands are going to get processed, like in:

```
list  dw  xCls
      db  'cls', 13
      dw  xHelp
      db  'help', 13
      dw  xDate
      db  'date', 13
      dw  xFail
  ...

  cld
  mov  si, list
NextItemOnList:
  lodsw                 ; Address of command's execution
  mov  bx, ax
  mov  di, buf          ; Contains the command we want to find (terminated by 13)
NextChar:
  lodsb
  scasb
  jne  NotThisOne
  cmp  al, 13
  jne  NextChar
Found:
  ...
NotThisOne:
  dec  si               ; Back to where the mismatch occured
SkipRemainder:
  lodsb                 ; Skip remainder of this list item
  cmp  al, 13
  jne  SkipRemainder
  cmp  word [si], xFail ; EndOfList ?
  jne  NextItemOnList   ; No
NotFound:
  ...
```