# What is the use of Int 13H AH=00h

Tags: assembly, virtualbox, interrupt, x86-16, bios

I don't understand the use of Int 13H AH=00h on my virtual floppy img.

I created an img virtual diskette from the command line:

> ```
> copy amorce.com/B+programme.com/B disk.img /Y
> ```

The floppy disk is called "disk.img". It is made up of a boot sector which was in "amorce.com" and the boot sector is contained in the first sector of the diskette of 512 bytes. The floppy disk also contains a program which takes up 6 sectors, so from 2 to 7.

I then put my floppy disk on a virtual machine without an operating system with virtual box. The machine launches the boot sector program directly.

In the boot sector code I get these lines of code:

```
initialise_disque: 
    mov dl, 0
    xor ax, ax 
    int 0x13 
    jc initialise_disque
```

No errors detected in this code, except that the problem is that I don't understand its usefulness.
The documentation tells me that it resets the floppy disk system, but what does that mean in this context?

When I remove these lines of code it doesn't change anything in the rest of the code.

To try to understand the usefulness of this function I checked if, after performing it, it deleted the programs contained in the floppy disk, but this is not the case.

I also added code in my boot sector to write on sectors 2 to 7 in order to overwrite the other program contained in the floppy disk. Then I called this reset function to check if it was okay put back the crashed program, but no results.

This is the [entire boot sector code](https://esauvage.developpez.com/tutoriels/asm/assembleur-intel-avec-nasm/amorce.asm).

What is the use of Int 13H AH=00h and what does reset mean in this context?

Comment: "Then I called this reset function to check **if it was okay put back the crashed program, but no results**. It remains unclear what you mean to say here! eg. Did *you* undo your overwriting of sectors 2 to 7, or did you hope for the reset function to do that *for you*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the use of Int 13H AH=00h and what does reset mean in this context?

The BIOS.ResetDiskSystem function 00h will *reset the controller* for the drive selected through the DL register. In this context, **'reset' means forcing the drive to pull its head to track 0** so the next I/O operation can start from track 0. It is this recalibration that sometimes causes a grinding sound after a disk error occured. You won't hear that while on your virtual machine!

Whenever a disk function like BIOS.ReadDiskSectors function 02h or BIOS.WriteDiskSectors function 03h reports an error, it is best to retry the failed operation a few times before giving up after consistent failure. In between tries you use this function so the disk operation can then start from a well-defined and safe starting point, in casu track 0.

> To try to understand the usefulness of this function I checked if after performing it it deleted the programs contained in the floppy disk, but this is not the case.

Rest assured, using this function does not delete any files on the disk, nor does it overwrite any sectors.

---

> ```
> initialise_disque: ; Initialise le lecteur de disque
>  xor ax, ax
>  int 0x13
>  jc initialise_disque; En cas d'erreur on recommence (sinon, de toute façon, on ne peut rien faire)
>
> lire:
>  mov ax, 0x1000 ; ES:BX = 1000:0000
>  xor bx, bx
>  mov es, ax
>  mov ah, 2 ; Fonction 0x02 : chargement mémoire
>  mov al, 6 ; On s'arrête au secteur n° 6
>  xor ch, ch ; Premier cylindre (n° 0)
>  mov cl, 2 ; Premier secteur (porte le n° 2, le n° 1, on est dedans, et le n° 0 n'existe pas)
>  ; Ca fait donc 5 secteurs
>  xor dh, dh ; Tête de lecture n° 0
>  ; Toujours pas d'identifiant de disque, c'est toujours le même.
>  int 0x13 ; Lit !
>  jc lire ; En cas d'erreur, on recommence
> ```

There's little sense in repeating the reset function on its own. Use it in the same loop that tries to read the disk sectors. Preferrably using a count (like 5 times) so you don't keep trying indefinitely and can inform the user about the catastrophical fail.

> ```
>  mov al, 6 ; On s'arrête au secteur n° 6
>  ; Ca fait donc 5 secteurs
> ```

This is wrong. The argument in AL specifies the *number of sectors* that you want to read. Starting from sector 2 (CL=2), you would read sectors 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and **7**. That's 6 in total.

Your VESA code overwrites the disk id that BIOS gave you in the DL register on boot. Better preserve that value so you can use it in this part of the program.
I see that the `mov dl,0` instruction in the question's code snippet is nowhere to be found in the full code that you have provided a link for!

Comment: The tutorial I am following contains errors, I added mov dl,0 in order to debug the code

Can I have a concrete example of Int 13H AH=00h
An example coded in nasm on a processor operating in 16 BITS mode

So that I can understand it in practice it is necessary that Int 13H AH=00h has an influence on the code, that if I remove it it causes an error or a change

Comment: @BastienPortigo An example that uses NASM is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216893/disk-read-error-while-loading-sectors-into-memory/34382681#34382681. Whether removing the BIOS.ResetDiskSystem function from that code would cause a change is unsure, I would even say unprobable. The number of reasons why a disk I/O can fail are no doubt numerous, but forcing the drive to pull its head to track 0, will only help if the original error was due to inaccuracies in the drive's addressing mechanism (hardware).

Comment: @BastienPortigo "inaccuracies in the drive's addressing mechanism" means that it could matter whether we move to a particular sector on the drive coming from a lower-numbered sector or from a higher-numbered sector. Nothing in the world can stop immediately, so neither can drive heads.

Comment: Have you ever personally had an error with BIOS.ReadDiskSectors function 02h or BIOS.WriteDiskSectors function 03h which forced you to use Int 13H AH=00h and which was impossible to resolve without a reset?

Maybe 13H AH=00h is not useful on a virtual machine and that it only has an impact on a real floppy disk?