# Concrete and useful example of Int 13H AH=00h

Tags: assembly, virtualbox, interrupt, x86-16, bios

Can I have a concrete and useful example of `Int 13H AH=00h`. An example coded in nasm on a processor operating in 16 BITS mode so that I can understand in practice, `Int 13H AH=00h` must have an influence on the code, if I delete it it causes an error or a change.

I use an img floppy disk on virtualbox and I am on boot sector.

I understood the theory: `Int 13H AH=00h` RESET DISK SYSTEM
Forces controller to recalibrate drive heads (seek to track 0).

I want to go further than theory and understand with example code with real use for `Int 13H AH=00h`.

The [tutorial](https://esauvage.developpez.com/tutoriels/asm/assembleur-intel-avec-nasm/amorce.asm) that I am following uses `Int 13H AH=00h` but it has no impact on the code, it is of no use, on the contrary I need a practical example with real usefulness and impact for `Int 13H AH=00h`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77416720/what-is-the-use-of-int-13h-ah-00h

Comment: there is no concrete and useful example on this link

Comment: It is said that some units, particularly diskette drives, may be unreliable and require multiple read requests until one of them succeeds. This is why loaders typically will retry a read request some amount of times. "Resetting" the unit using an int 13h service 00h call between two attempts is best practice to help the drive to succeed eventually. On modern or virtual systems it may be superfluous however.

Comment: 2) Have you ever personally had an error with BIOS.ReadDiskSectors function 02h or BIOS.WriteDiskSectors function 03h which forced you to use Int 13H AH=00h and which was impossible to resolve without a reset?

Maybe 13H AH=00h is not useful on a virtual machine and that it only has an impact on a real floppy disk?

Comment: *Maybe 13H AH=00h is not useful on a virtual machine* - I'd expect that to be true!  Software doesn't drift out of alignment and need recalibration, unless it's intentionally emulating imperfect hardware!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Int 13H AH=00h is useless on a virtual machine like VirtualBox as [this documentation says](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Ecelio/mc404-2004/service_interrupts#int13h_00h)

If Int 13H AH=00h is used outside VM later, it is relevant to leave it.

It's impossible to have a concrete and useful example with a real impact on the code of Int 13H AH=00h on a virtual machine. No working example on google, stackoverflow, chatgpt

With the advent of SSD drives, the function no longer really has any use, and especially since int 0x13 is no longer used in a modern OS using UEFI where real mode BIOS functions remain present for backwards compatibility.

Comment: There is official IBM documentation for the IBM-PC ROM BIOS archived here: http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/ibm/pc/ps2/PS2_and_PC_BIOS_Interface_Technical_Reference_Apr87.pdf (disk reset int 13h/ah=2 is documented . Virtual machines don't have mechanical parts like real floppies so a disk reset may have no observable effect and some kinds of errors on a virtual device are not possible.

Comment: As for a concrete example one could always look at a boot sector for MS-DOS all the way back to 2.00. In that primitive boot sector a volume boot record is chained and in that code int 13h/ah=2 gets called and if the carry flag is set it then does a disk reset (int 13h/ah=0) and tries again (up to 5 times). Someone disassembled the MS-DOS 2.00 bootloader here: https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/200MBR.htm . Search for `065E BF0500` and that is the code I am referring to.

Comment: Back in the good ole days (in the late 80s) disk errors on floppies was very common especially on marginal cheapo disks.

Comment: In my first comment "disk reset int 13h/ah=2 is documented" should have been "disk reset int 13h/ah=0 is documented"

Comment: Ralf Brown has an interrupt list that is considered the Bible for BIOS/MS-DOS interrupt calls. The types of errors that different kinds of real world devices could possibly encounter are listed here: https://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0606.htm#Table234

Comment: I can only end with this note: If you write code that uses Int 13h for read/writes etc and you never use int 13/ah=0 your code will likely always work on virtual machines, and it will likely work on most media on real hardware. **If you try it on real floppy mechanical hardware that we had a generation ago (with cheap disk media) then you may find your code is less resilient than code that retries disk operations with a reset when an error is detected.**

Comment: I have a bootloader using NASM that does 3 disk retries if there is an error (you can set it to 5 or something else). Between each retry a disk reset is done. That can be found here in `boot.asm` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54894585/legacy-bios-bootloader-to-bootstrap-real-mode-code-in-second-stage . Just look for references to `.disk_error`

Answer (score 1):

Well, for example, this is qemu mbr code. Check part between `******`.

`di = 5` is number of attempts to read from disk. So if error occures `CF = 1`, code decrements `di` and after 5 attempts we have `di = 0` and in next step code generates message `"Error loading operating system"`.

```
+       fa                  cli                         ; clear IF
+       33 c0               xor ax,ax                   ; ax = 0000
+       8e d0               mov ss,ax                   ; ss = 0000
+       bc 00 7c            mov sp,7c00                 ; sp = 7c00     
+       8b f4               mov si,sp                   ; si = 7c00
+       50                  push ax                     ; ↑ ax = 0000
+       07                  pop es                      ; ↓ es = 0000
+       50                  push ax                     ; ↑ ax = 0000
+       1f                  pop ds                      ; ↓ ds = 0000   
+       fb                  sti                         ; set IF
+       fc                  cld                         ; clear DF
        
        // copy 512 bytes (2 * 256), ds:si [0000:7c00] -> es:di [0000:0600]
        
+       bf 00 06            mov di,0600                 ; di = 0600
+       b9 00 01            mov cx,0100                 ; cx = 0100(256)
+       f2                  repnz                       ; if != 0
+       a5                  movsw                       ; copy 256 words
+       ea 1d 06 00 00      jmp 0000:061d                   
        
+       be be 07            mov si,07be                 ; partition table offset
        
+       b3 04               mov bl,04                   ; 4 entries
+3      80 3c 80            cmp byte ptr [si],80        ; 80 = active partiton
+1>     74 0e               jz +14                      ; 80 found
+       80 3c 00            cmp byte ptr [si],00        ; no entry      
+2>     75 1c               jnz +28                     ; other system
+       83 c6 10            add si,+10                  ; check next entry
+       fe cb               dec bl                      ; dec number of records     
+3>     75 ef               jnz -17                     ; if nothing found, check again, next record
    
+       cd 18               int 18                      ; rom bios
        
        // read from partition table record
        
+1      8b 14               mov dx,[si]                 ; [07be] = dh(head) = 01 dl(drive number) = 80 
+       8b 4c 02            mov cx,[si + 02]            ; [07c0] = ch(cylinder) = 00 cl(sector number ) = 01 
+       8b ee               mov bp,si                   ; bp = 07be, first partition table entry
+5      83 c6 10            add si,+10                  ; move to next record
+       fe cb               dec bl                      ; dec number of records     
+4>     74 1a               jz +26                      ; no more records, read sector
+       80 3c 00            cmp byte ptr [si],00        ; no entry? check next or show "invalid partition table"
+5>     74 f4               jz -12                      ; 1111 0100 , 0000 1011, 0000 1100, -0c
        
+2      be 8b 06            mov si,068b                 ; "invalid partition table"
+7,9,11 ac                  lodsb                       ; al = ds:si
+       3c 00               cmp al,00                   ; end of string?
+6>     74 0b               jz +11                      ; go infinity loop
+       56                  push si                     ; ↑ si = 07fe, offset 55 AA
+       bb 07 00            mov bx,0007                 ; 
+       b4 0e               mov ah,0e                   ; tty show char
+       cd 10               int 10                      ; graphics int  
        
+       5e                  pop si                      ; ↓ si = 07fe, 55 aa
+7>     eb f0               jmp -16                     ; load next char, 1111 0000, 0000 1111, 0001 0000, -16
+6>     eb fe               jmp -2                      ; infinity loop, stop working
*********************************************************       
+4      bf 05 00            mov di,0005                 ; di = 0005, if disk error, we have 5 tries
+10     bb 00 7c            mov bx,7c00                 ; buffer, es:bx = 0000:7c00
+       b8 01 02            mov ax,0201                 ; ah = 02 read, al = 01 1 sector
+       57                  push di                     ; ↑ di = 0005
+       cd 13               int 13h                     ; disk int
        
+       5f                  pop di                      ; ↓ di = 0005
+8>     73 0c               jnb +12                     ; no errors?
+       33 c0               xor ax,ax                   ; error, ax = 0000, reset disk system
+       cd 13               int 13h                     ; disk int  

+       4f                  dec di                      ; decrement number of tries 
+10>    75 ed               jnz -19                     ; if not 0, try again, 1110 1101, 0001 0011, -19
+       be a3 06            mov si,06a3                 ; si = offset "Error loading operating system" 
+11>    eb d3               jmp -45                     ; go lodsb, 1101 0011, 0010 1101, -45
*********************************************************
+8      be c2 06            mov si, 06c2                ; si = offset "Missing operating system"
+       bf fe 7d            mov di,7dfe                 ; di = offset 55 AA
        
+       81 3d 55 aa         cmp word ptr [di],aa55      ; [di] == 55 aa?
+9>     75 c7               jnz -57                     ; go lodsb, 1100 0111, 0011 1001, -57
+       8b f5               mov si,bp                   ; si = 07be, first partition table entry 
+       ea 00 7c 00 00      jmp 0000:7c00               ; jmp to new loaded data
```

Comment: When I remove Int 13H AH=00h it doesn't change anything in the code, it has no influence in your example, maybe 13H AH=00h is not useful on a virtual machine and it has an impact only on a real floppy disk?

Comment: I think program should take into account all possible outcomes and inform user that something is wrong with hardware. What if hdd will start to misbehave? I don't know what is the probability that this will happen but better to have code which has some protection against this cases.

Comment: Have you ever personally had an error with BIOS.ReadDiskSectors function 02h or BIOS.WriteDiskSectors function 03h which forced you to use Int 13H AH=00h and which was impossible to resolve without a reset?